# Trying to shorten my code with dict

Tags: python, if-statement, dictionary, int

```
tala = int(input('Skrifaðu magn af pening-->'))
if tala >= 0:
    fth = int(tala / 5000)
    remains = tala % 5000
    tth = int(remains / 2000)
    remains = remains % 2000
    th = int(remains / 1000)
    remains = remains % 1000
    fhr = int(remains / 500)
    remains = remains % 500
    hdr = int(remains / 100)
    remains = remains % 100
    fty = int(remains / 50)
    remains = remains % 50
    ten = int(remains / 10)
    remains = remains % 10
    fiv = int(remains / 5)
    remains = remains % 5
    one = int(remains / 1)
    print(d[tala])
```

**the print part is the main focus of the question**
i'm unfamiliar with the syntax, but the plan was to use dict to avoid making tons of if's to tell the code what to do if the number is bigger than 5000 or if its bigger than 2000, etc.
basically i had something like this in mind (invalid syntax ofc)

```
d = {}
##d[Value between 0 and 4] or d[value between 5 and 9] etc.
d[0-4] = ("That would be {0} Krónur.".format(one))
d[5-9] = ("That would be {1} Fimmkallar and {0} Krónur.".format(one,fiv))
d[10-49] = ("That would be {2} Tíkallar, {1} Fimmkallar and {0} Krónur.".format(one,fiv,ten))
d[50-99] = ("That would be {3} Fimmtíukallar, {2} Tíkallar, {1} Fimmkallar and {0} Krónur.".format(one,fiv,ten,fty))
```

**If you're wondering what this code is doing,** is if i'd say enter a value of higher than 5000

it would split it down (sortof like an ATM) to how many times it's 5000 bill, 2000 bill,1000 bill, 500 bill, 100 coins, etc.

It was a school project resolving around usage of the % sign (it was made for C# however, but i'm learning python through doing my C# assignments in Python)

The Main question is: **If theres a way to make that dictionary style work i'd love to know how.**
Secondary questions are:
If theres a better way to do this i'd love to hear your ideas.
If i should be doing it (or parts of it) some other way that won't hurt to know either.

Edit: i found a semi functional solution, but its not exactly pretty. It is however a lot more readable than my alternative, so its better than nothing, doesn't anyone have a better idea than this?:

```
#Dictionary START
    if tala < 5:
        num = 0
    elif tala < 10:
        num = 1
    elif tala < 50:
        num = 2
    elif tala < 100:
        num = 3
    d = {}
    d[0] =("Það eru {0} Krónur.".format(one))
    d[1] =("Það eru {1} Fimmkallar og {0} Krónur.".format(one,fiv))
    ...
#Dictionary END
    print(d[num])
```

Comment: I found a semi-functional soluton, which is to make if sentance and a new variable
(for example)
if tala < 5:
    num = 0
elif tala < 10:
    num = 1

then make
d[num] instead of d[tala]

Not a satisfactory solution but i think it looks way prettier than if i wouldn't be using a dictionary as a final result( also i removed the commas and placed string format instead)

Answer (score 0):

First, create a dictionary mapping the names of the units to the previously extracted values:

```
d = {"Kronur": one, "Tikallar": ten, "Fimmtiukallar": fty, ...}
```

You can use `collections.OrderedDict` to preserve the order in which items are added to the dictionary. However, as others pointed out, using a list of tuples might be better since you care more for order than for quick random access:

```
d = [..., ("Tikallar", ten), ("Fimmkallar", fiv), ("Kronur", one)]
```

Now, you can loop over the items in the dictionary (those that are not `0`) and concatenate them to a long string. (When using the list of tuples, use `for (key, val) in d` instead of `for (key, val) in d.items()`.)

```
def get_string(d):
    s = "That would be "
    not_zero = [(key, val) for (key, val) in d.items() if val > 0]
    for i, (key, val) in enumerate(not_zero):
        if i > 0:
            s += ", " if i < len(not_zero)-1 else " and "
        s += "%d %s" % (val, key)
    s += "."
    return s
```

Example output:

```
>>> d = {"Kronur": 4, "Tikallar": 0, "Fimmtiukallar": 2}
>>> print get_string(d)
"That would be 2 Fimmtiukallar and 4 Kronur."
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for, but i'm having a hard time making the values  spawn in the proper order. say

759 
outputs: that would be 1 fimmkall, 4 krónur, 2 hundraðkallar, and 1 fimmtíukall --
but should be: that would be 2 hundraðkallar, 1 1 fimmtíkuall, 1 fimmkall and 4 krónur

How to fix?

Comment: @Rabcor As I said, you might want to use an `OrderedDict` and insert the values in the order you want them to be printed. However, as others have pointed out, it may be wiser to use a list of tuples instead of a dict, since you care for order, not for quick random access.

Answer (score 0):

If you first specify a list of all the denominations that you have, and then, you can use a for loop to iterate through each of the denominations, and then use a list comprehension to output an array of substrings. Here is an examples with some tests.

```
#specify array containing denominations as a tuple, amount and name
denominations = [(5000, 'five thousand'), (2000, 'two thousand'), (1000, 'five thousand'), (500, 'five hundred'), (100, 'one hundred')]

def print_break_down(total):

    counts = []
    for denomination in denominations:
        counts.append(total/ denomination[0])
        total = total % denomination[0]

    main = ' and '.join(['%s %s' %(count, denominations[i][1]) for i, count in enumerate(counts) if count>0])
    print 'That would be %s' % main

print_break_down(15000)
print_break_down(15100)
print_break_down(5300)
print_break_down(4000)
print_break_down(1600)
print_break_down(600)
print_break_down(100)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work as you want, not using a `dict` because the lookup is not used so the advantage of the
`dict` is lost

```
def test_func(value):
    """
        >>> test_func(0)
        'That would be 0 Kronur.'

        >>> test_func(4)
        'That would be 4 Kronur.'

        >>> test_func(5)
        'That would be 1 Fimmkallar and 0 Kronur.'

        >>> test_func(15)
        'That would be 1 Tikallar, 1 Fimmkallar and 0 Kronur.'

        >>> test_func(47)
        'That would be 2 Fimmtiukallar, 0 Tikallar, 1 Fimmkallar and 2 Kronur.'
    """
    twenty = value / 20
    ten = (value - twenty * 20) / 10
    five = (value - twenty * 20 - ten * 10) / 5
    one = (value - twenty * 20 - ten * 10 - five * 5)
    ranges = [((0, 5), 'That would be {0} Kronur.'),
              ((5, 10), 'That would be {1} Fimmkallar and {0} Kronur.'),
              ((10, 20), 'That would be {2} Tikallar, {1} Fimmkallar and '
                         '{0} Kronur.'),
              ((20, 50), 'That would be {3} Fimmtiukallar, {2} Tikallar, '
                         '{1} Fimmkallar and {0} Kronur.')]
    text = next(v for r, v in ranges if r[0] <= value < r[1])
    return text.format(one, five, ten, twenty)
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html